# VUE route redirect not closing modal from other page

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I am using `vue2` `routes` set up by another dev but I am trying to change the 'redirect' currently set to go to the 'home' page.

This issue is that there is a page which when you first enter the page (for the very first time) a `bootstrap` `modal` is displayed. The issue I'm having is if I enter this page of the first time then change the URL, the 'redirect' is working as expected BUT the modal is also still displaying and I don't know how to make it close.

**routes.js**

```
import {store} from './store/store';
import Cart from './components/Cart';
import Stock from './components/Stock';
import Home from './components/Home.vue';
import Review from './components/Review';
import Order from './components/Order.vue';
import OrderReport from './components/OrderReport';
import AccountDetails from './components/AccountDetails';
import ExistingOrders from './components/ExistingOrders';

export const routes = [
    {path: '', component: Home},
    {path: '/order', component: Order},
    {
        path: '/review', component: Review, children: [
            {path: '', component: ExistingOrders},
            {
                path: ':id', component: OrderReport, beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {

                    let orderCount = store.getters.orderPaginator.items.filter(item => item.id === +to.params.id).length;

                    next(orderCount > 0);
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {path: '/account', component: AccountDetails},
    {path: '/stock', component: Stock},
    {path: '/cart', component: Cart},
    {path: '*', redirect: '/order'}
];
```

If I change "redirect: '/order'" to "redirect: '/'" it goes to my home page as expected but with the modal displayed. Is there a way to close on the redirect?

**Page where modal should be displayed**
[image]

**Changed URL to 'orders' and clicked 'Enter'
[image]

Directed to the correct page (Home page) but modal still displayed. Is there a way I can change the `:key` using `routes` or would I have to use something like `this.$forceUpdate()`, although I have read that this may not work in `vue2` and is really a nice thing to do.

What's my best approach? Just to mention I am new to `vue2`

Comment: It's likely that the modal is defined outside of the <router-view> tag and so doesn't update when you change the url. It depends how it's being displayed... is there a data attribute in vue linked to the visibility of the modal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had success with this approach.

You can use a feature called [Global Before Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards) in Vue Router.

Inside `router` folder `index.js` file:

```
const router = createRouter({
  // not relevant to the answer
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // remove modal backdrop if one exists
  let modalBackground = document.querySelector('.modal-backdrop')
  if (modalBackground) {
    modalBackground.remove()
  }
  // do other stuff

  next()
})
```

In my case I wanted to remove the modal backdrop but you can modify this to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the cleanest or best way to resolve the issue but the only way I could think of was to use the following in my 'home.vue' file

```
mounted() {
    this.closeAccountSelectModal();
},

methods: {
    closeAccountSelectModal() {
        $('.modal ').modal('hide');
    }
}
```

Used the `class` so all other pages which have `modals` will also be covered by it.

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late but you can watch for route changes in components so when the route changes just close the modal

```
 watch:{
        $route (to, from){
    
            // hide modal
        }
    }
```